# jQuery and masonry(): animated objects flickering in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-masonry

I am loading a couple of `<li>` elements on a page via `.ajax()` and stack them on top of each other. The user can then

- drag individual elements around
- click on "pile" to rebuild the stack
- click on "spread" to spread elements out with [jquery.masonry()](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

The problem occurs in the last option: When spreading out the items, the elements go to their designated position in the grid as they should and then **flash for a little moment back to their original position.**

See a video here: [Video](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18268/jquery-flickr/jquery-flickr.mov) (Quicktime .mov)
See a live demo here: [Live Demo](http://mgieselmann.com/k/kd202/index.htm)

The problem only occurs about 50% of the time, not every time I spread the items. For instance, in the video above it only happens the second and the last time I click on "spread". I have not been able to tell what exactly causes the bug to occur.
The problem occurs in Chrome 29.0.1547.57 on a Mac. Firefox 22 and Safari 6.0.5 are not affected. I haven't tried any other browsers yet.

When the spread link is clicked .masonry() is called this way:

```
    $('.content').masonry({
        columnWidth: 180,
        gutter: 20,
        itemSelector: 'li',
        isResizeBound: false,
        isLayoutInstant: false
    });
```

I am thankful for hints on how to solve this.

**Update:** I noticed that the problem also occurs on other sites which use jquery.masonry, such as the plugin's site itself. See the video here: [Video](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18268/masonry-flicker.mov). Do other people have the same issue or is this my setup (OS X 10.7.5, Chrome 29.0.1547.57)?

Comment: I've found this too after I just recently upgraded to Masonry v3.1.2 and in Chrome. They slide into place, then out of place (off to the left and right of the page), then back into place. I haven't set any options at all - just using CSS percentage widths on each item. If I set transitionDuration: 0 I find the items are simply stuck in the wrong place.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. It was caused due to the CSS transitions on the `grid-item`'s style. **Removing the CSS3 transitions** for the specific DOM elements solved my issue.

Comment: This actually helped my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just found this while searching for the same problem. I was starting to wonder if it was my monitor or cable.

I'm using Windows 8 and Chrome Version 30.0.1599.101 m